# Python O365 Authentication Problems When Scheduled

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, windows-task-scheduler, o365-flow

I have a script to do a web scrape and send the data in an email via the O365 package. I've registered the app with Azure, and completed the authentication flow and **the code runs fine in Jupyter Notebook**. However, problems begin when I try to run the script via Task Scheduler or in a batch file. Here is the code:

```
content = html_template.format(df.to_html(index=False))
credentials = ('AzureappID', 'azureSecret')
account = Account(credentials)
m = account.new_message()
m.to.add('email@x.com')
m.subject = 'Test'
m.body = content
m.send()
```

The batch file shows me this error, which appears to occur on the `m.send()` line:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\O365\message.py", line 694, in send
   response = self.con.post(url, data=data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py", line 787, in post
   return self.oauth_request(url, 'post', data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py", line 763, in oauth_request
   self.session = self.get_session(load_token=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\O365\connection.py", line 539, in get_session
   raise RuntimeError('No auth token found. Authentication Flow needed')
  RuntimeError: No auth token found. Authentication Flow needed
```

It appears to say the token has been loaded, but then in the "get_session" line says no token has been found. As I said, the code runs fine in Jupyter - it seems as though task scheduler/the batch file cannot find the token. I've seen [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/13912/) that the token may need to be saved in a root directory, but I'm not sure where the token is stored, or what the appropriate root directory would be for storage.

Any thoughts on this auth flow?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Per the docs, the user should use FileSystemTokenBackend. I ended up creating a file named 'o365_token.txt' and storing this in the same folder as my script. I believe this is the default name of the file once you create the token with FileSystemTokenBackend. 
[O365 Documentation FileSystemTokenBackend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H36j1.png)

Comment: I had meant to post an answer to this myself.  I agree the key is the token must be saved **in the same folder as the script,** however, my problem is when I was running this script via task scheduler, it still would not work.  The other requirement that made it work for me, was to specify the task "Start in" the folder containing the script and token.  That argument is available in task scheduler while editing the action.  If you can edit your answer to include that I will mark it as correct.  Thanks